# C# multiple sequence ? conditional operator

Tags: c#

I got an exam and saw a question like;

```
var b = (1==2) ? (1==1) ? (2==1) ? "A" : "B" : "C" : "D";
```

What is the b and how it works a condition like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `(1==2) ? (1==1) ? (2==1) ? "A" : "B" : "C" : "D"`?

Comment: yes I mean that. thanks for warning I review the question

Answer (score 2):

[A ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) acts as such:
The statement

```
variable = condition ? value1 : value2
```

is equivalent to

```
if (condition) 
{
  variable = value1;
} 
else 
{
  variable = value2;
}
```

So in your case,

```
var b = (1==2) ? (1==1) ? (2==1) ? "A" : "B" : "C" : "D";
```

is simply a few nested ternary operators, and is the same as

```
    var b; 
    if (1==2)
    {
      if (1==1) 
      {
        if (2==1) 
        {
          b = "A";
        }
        else 
        {
         b = "B";
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        b = "C";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      b = "D";
    }
```

Comment: `b` immediately goes out of scope in your example, so it's not quite the same :)

Comment: Fair enough, I changed the example so that b remains in scope after the conditional blocks.